# Android Monkey: "No activities found to run, monkey aborted"

Tags: android, android-monkey

My package is named com.mywebsite.banana.

- I want to have a seed, so the test is repeatable: -s 13
- I want to have a fairly low-level of verbosity: -v
- I want to run 500 psuedo-random commands: 500

**I'm calling monkey like this**:

```
adb shell monkey -s 13 -p com.mywebsite.banana -v 500
```

**My output**:

```
:Monkey: seed=13 count=500
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
No activities found to run, monkey aborted
```

My AndroidManifest.xml has this in it:

```
<categoy android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I need to add to my app before running the monkey? The main activity is located in com.mywebsite.banana - is that the correct path to be passed in, or should it go all the way to the activity like this: com.mywebsite.banana.activityName?

From what I've read, it seems as though I'm doing this correctly:

- http://dnlkntt.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/how-to-stress-test-your-android-app-with-monkey/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_testing.htm
- http://hariniachala.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-application-ui-testing-with.html

---

**Edit**

Attempt 1:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.mywebsite.banana -c intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER -v 500
```

Result 1:

```
:Monkey: seed=13 count=500
:AllowPackage: com.mywebsite.banana
:IncludeCategory: intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER  
// Warning: no activities found for category intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted
```

Attempt 2:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.mywebsite.banana -c android.intent.category.MONKEY -v 500
```

Result 2:

```
:Monkey: seed=13 count=500
:AllowPackage: com.mywebsite.banana
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY 
No activities found to run, monkey aborted
```

Attempt 3:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.mywebsite.banana -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -c android.intent.category.MONKEY -v 500
```

Result 3:

```
:Monkey: seed=13 count=500
:AllowPackage: com.mywebsite.banana
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY 
No activities found to run, monkey aborted
```

Some of the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mywebsite.banana.FRCActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="none" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also tried this version of the manifest, with no change:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.mywebsite.banana.FRCActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: "Monkey aborted" - now that sounds just plain out wrong...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK! I figured this out. The error that is shown is indeed correct:

```
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted
```

This means that the package name I was using was incorrect. I stared and stared and stared, and finally my colleague mentioned that **our build system changes the name of the package before pushing it to the device**

So, if you are getting this error, **make sure you actually know what the name of your package is**.

So, the final command that worked was this:

```
$ adb shell monkey -p com.mywebsite.banana.newname -v 5
```

By the way, correct output from this monkey command looks like this:

```
:Monkey: seed=1418671144561 count=5
:AllowPackage: com.mywebsite.banana.newname
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
// Event percentages:
//   0: 15.0%
//   1: 10.0%
//   2: 2.0%
//   3: 15.0%
//   4: -0.0%
//   5: 25.0%
//   6: 15.0%
//   7: 2.0%
//   8: 2.0%
//   9: 1.0%
//   10: 13.0%
:Switch: #Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.mywebsite.banana.newname/com.mywebsite.banana.MyActivity;end
// Allowing start of Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mywebsite.banana.newname/com.mywebsite.banana.MyActivity } in package com.mywebsite.banana.newname
Events injected: 5
:Sending rotation degree=0, persist=false
:Dropped: keys=0 pointers=0 trackballs=0 flips=0 rotations=0
## Network stats: elapsed time=175ms (0ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 175ms not connected)
// Monkey finished
```

**One final note**: I did NOT need to add `android.intent.category.MONKEY` to my AndroidManifest.xml file!

Comment: in my case I missed following line: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> in manifest

Comment: As a tip, you can find out the package names of apps on the device using: `adb shell pm list packages -3` (the -3 limits the list to third-party apps, and unless you work for Google/Android/a device manufacturer, yours is probably a third-party app :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to @ncrypticus's answer, I think the easiest way to find out the final package name is to open the app on the emulator and then in Android Studio go to Tools -> Layout Inspector. This will show you the package name of that app.

Answer (score 0):

For me to find name of a package (which was also changed) i try this:

```
$ adb shell monkey --ignore-crashes -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -v 10000 > text_logs.txt
```

It was logged a lot of intents and all of them pointed to packages names in between was also mine.

Comment: Warning: Running this opened tons of applications randomly on my phone.